# Получить ip программы-сервера (Linux)

Tags: c++, linux, сокет, ip

```
ОС : Ubuntu (Linux)
```

Ниже мой класс `Server`. В нем есть метод `void myListen()`, в котором я пытаюсь выудить айпишники сервера и клиента. С клиентом все выходит, а вот айпишник сервера представляется мне как `0.0.0.0`, что, естественно, меня не устраивает. Как получить реальный айпи, к которому подключился клиент?

```
class Server{
    private:
        int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, pid;
        struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr, *tmp_addr_in;
        socklen_t clilen, servlen;
        struct sockaddr *tmp_addr;



    public:
        Server(int port) : portno(port) {
            sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
            if (sockfd < 0)
                error("ERROR opening socket");

            bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
            serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
            serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
            serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

            if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
                error("ERROR on binding");      
        }

        ~Server(){
            close(sockfd);
        }

        void myListen(){
            listen(sockfd,5);


            clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
            char bufClientIp[64];
            char bufServerIp[64];
            while (1) {
                newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);



                inet_ntop(AF_INET, &cli_addr.sin_addr, 
                bufClientIp, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);

                struct sockaddr sa;

                servlen = sizeof(tmp_addr);
                if(getsockname(sockfd, &sa, &servlen) == -1){
                    error("ERROR on getsockname");
                }

                tmp_addr_in = (sockaddr_in*)tmp_addr;

                inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(tmp_addr_in->sin_addr), 
                bufServerIp, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);

                std::cout<<"Server -> "<<bufServerIp<<std::endl;
                std::cout<<"Client -> "<<bufClientIp<<std::endl;

                if (newsockfd < 0) 
                    error("ERROR on accept");

                pid = fork();
                if (pid < 0)
                    error("ERROR on fork");
                if (pid == 0)  {
                    while(1){



                        close(sockfd);
                        myReceive();    

                    }
                    exit(0);
                }
                else close(newsockfd);
            } /* end of while */
        }

        void myReceive (){
            int bitsReceived;

            char buffer[256];      
            bzero(buffer,256);
            bitsReceived = read(newsockfd, buffer, 255);

            if (bitsReceived < 0) 
                error("ERROR reading from socket");
            printf("Here is the message: %s\n", buffer);
            bitsReceived = write(newsockfd,"I got your message",18);
            if (bitsReceived < 0) 
                error("ERROR writing to socket");
        }

    };
```

### РЕШЕНИЕ :

Основываясь на примере господина avp, я изменил свою функцию `void myListen()` до рабочего состояния и в `private` секции изменил тип `cli_addr` с `struct sockaddr_in` на `struct sockaddr`:

```
void myListen(){

        listen(sockfd,5);       

        std::string szClientIp;
        std::string szServerIp;
        int szClientPort;
        int szServerPort;

        while (1) {
        newsockfd = accept(sockfd, &cli_addr, &clilen);

            if (getpeername(newsockfd, &cli_addr, &clilen) == -1)
              perror("getpeername");
            else
            szClientIp = inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)&cli_addr)->sin_addr);
            szClientPort = ntohs(((struct sockaddr_in *)&cli_addr)->sin_port);
            std::cout<<"Client Ip : > "<<szClientIp<<std::endl;
            std::cout<<"Client Port : > "<<szClientPort<<std::endl;     

            if (getsockname(newsockfd, &cli_addr, &clilen) == -1)
                perror("getsockname");
            else
            szServerIp = inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)&cli_addr)->sin_addr);
            szServerPort = ntohs(((struct sockaddr_in *)&cli_addr)->sin_port);
            std::cout<<"Server Ip : > "<<szServerIp<<std::endl;
            std::cout<<"Server Port : > "<<szServerPort<<std::endl;


            if (newsockfd < 0) 
                error("ERROR on accept");           
            pid = fork();
            if (pid < 0)
                error("ERROR on fork");
            if (pid == 0)  {
                while(1){
                    close(sockfd);
                    myReceive();                    
                }
                exit(0);
            }
            else 
                close(newsockfd);
        } /* end of while */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из вопроса совершенно не понятно, что именно не работает.

======

**Update  после появления кода**

Ваши ошибки вот тут

```
servlen = sizeof(tmp_addr);  // видим struct sockaddr *tmp_addr и похоже это не тот размер -)
if(getsockname(sockfd, &sa, &servlen) == -1){
    error("ERROR on getsockname");
}

tmp_addr_in = (sockaddr_in*)tmp_addr; // этот указатель
```

Смотрит неизвестно куда.

```
inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(tmp_addr_in->sin_addr), // вот тут Вам не повезло, прога НЕ УПАЛА (а то, сами бы в отладчике нашли)
bufServerIp, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
```

И все они связаны с `tmp_addr_in` и `tmp_addr`.

Похоже, надо написать просто

```
servlen = sizeof(sa);
if(getsockname(sockfd, &sa, &servlen) == -1){
    error("ERROR on getsockname");
}
inet_ntop(AF_INET, 
          &((struct sockaddr_in *)&sa)->sin_addr, // видимо тут-то Вы и запутались
          bufServerIp, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
```

======

Рискну предположить, что переменная `clilen` не инициализирована перед вызовом `accept()`.

B [man 2 accept](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html) написано:

> ```
>    The addrlen argument is a value-result argument: the caller  must  ini‐
>    tialize  it  to contain the size (in bytes) of the structure pointed to
>    by addr; on return it will contain the actual size of the peer address.
> ```

Т.е. напишите:

```
socklen_t clilen = (__typeof__(clilen))sizeof(cli_addr);
```

до вызова `accept()` (который может изменить ее значение).

Кроме того, имея "законнекченный" сокет, не важно у клиента или сервера, всегда можно узнать как собственный адрес (IP, port)

```
int getsockname(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t *addrlen);
```

так и адрес "визави"

```
int getpeername(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t *addrlen);
```

В обоих случаях параметр `addrlen` перед вызовом должен быть  инициализирован (аналогично примеру с `accept()`)  размером буфера для адреса, на который указывает `*addr`.

Вот пример:

```
avp@wubu:hashcode$ cat serv-ips.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define errExit(msg)    do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);   \
  } while (0)

static int
makeSimpleServer (char *cport) // default port = 12345
{
  int on = 1, asock = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (setsockopt(asock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&on, sizeof (on)) < 0)
    errExit("socket");

  short port = cport? atoi(cport): 12345;
  if (port < 1)
    port = 12345;
  struct sockaddr_in addr;
  int  laddr = sizeof(addr);
  memset (&addr, 0, laddr);
  addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  addr.sin_port = htons(port);
  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  if (bind(asock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, laddr))
    errExit("bind");

  struct linger ling;
  ling.l_onoff = 1;
  ling.l_linger = 2; // seconds after shudown sock for deliver data
  if (setsockopt(asock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, (char *)&ling, sizeof(ling)))
    errExit("linger");
  if (listen(asock, 128))
    errExit("listen");

  return asock;
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  // port av[1] (default 12345) and INADDR_ANY
  int asock = makeSimpleServer(av[1]); 
  int sock;
  struct sockaddr inadr;
  socklen_t       slen = sizeof(inadr);

  while ((sock = accept(asock, &inadr, &slen)) > 0) {
    printf ("New connection %s:%d\n",
        inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)&inadr)->sin_addr),
        ntohs(((struct sockaddr_in *)&inadr)->sin_port));
    if (getpeername(sock, &inadr, &slen) == -1)
      perror("getpeername");
    else
      printf("getpeername %s:%d\n",
         inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)&inadr)->sin_addr),
         ntohs(((struct sockaddr_in *)&inadr)->sin_port));
    if (getsockname(sock, &inadr, &slen) == -1)
      perror("getsockname");
    else
      printf("getsockname %s:%d\n",
         inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)&inadr)->sin_addr),
         ntohs(((struct sockaddr_in *)&inadr)->sin_port));

    close(sock);
    errno = 0;
  }

  perror("server exit");
}


avp@wubu:hashcode$ gcc serv-ips.c && ./a.out 
New connection 10.3.35.78:46980
getpeername 10.3.35.78:46980
getsockname 10.3.35.78:12345
New connection 127.0.0.1:50958
getpeername 127.0.0.1:50958
getsockname 127.0.0.1:12345
^C
avp@wubu:hashcode$
```

в другом окне, соответственно, запускал

```
avp@wubu:~$ nc 10.3.35.78 12345
avp@wubu:~$ nc localhost 12345
```

Как видите, у меня все работает.

**Update**

Рассмотрел, что у Вас проблема с вызовом `inet_ntop()`...
В соответствии с [man inet_ntop](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_ntop.3.html)

> ```
> The resulting string is
> copied to the buffer pointed to by dst, which must be a non-null
> pointer.  The caller specifies the number of bytes available in this
> buffer in the argument size.
> ```

....

> ```
>    AF_INET
>           src points to a struct in_addr (in network byte order) which
>           is converted to an IPv4 network address in the dotted-decimal
>           format, "ddd.ddd.ddd.ddd".  The buffer dst must be at least
>           INET_ADDRSTRLEN bytes long.
> ```

В коде примера ее надо вызывать вот так:

```
char buf[64];
inet_ntop(AF_INET,
          &((struct sockaddr_in *)&inadr)->sin_addr,
          buf, sizeof(buf) - 1)
```

Я проверил, действительно результаты те же, что и при вызове `inet_ntoa(...)`

Comment: Я изменил описание. Посмотри, пожалйста. Я пытался использовать getsockname, но мне возвращает 0.0.0.0

Comment: Надо `getsockname(newsockfd, &sa, &servlen)` -- т.е. сокет с которым работаешь, а не тот на который приходят сединения. С тем тоже все правильно -- нули это INADDRANY, т.е. принимаем с **любого интерфейса**

Comment: Про INADDRANY знаю. Не понимаю, как получить именно айпишник, к которому подключились, чтобы были не нули, а реальный адрес. я попробовал варианты 
getsockname(newsockfd, &sa, &servlen);
getpeername(newsockfd, &sa, &servlen);
getsockname(sockfd, &sa, &servlen);
getpeername(sockfd, &sa, &servlen);

Но все они показывают нули.
Вызывал эти функции там же.

Comment: Вам серверная сторона нужна (после accept)?

Comment: Обновил ответ кодом примерчика (все работает)

Comment: @LigvestO, с `inet_ntop()` тоже сделал (проверил, работает), только код в ответе менять не стал.

Comment: Ваши ошибки в коде тоже, похоже, нашел (см **Update**)

Comment: Использовал твой пример кода в своем классе. Сейчас все работает. С `inet_ntop()` не получилось, а вот с `inet_ntoa()` все отлично. Изменил заголовок поста - добавил туда решение. Спасибо за помощь.